# Is it possible to add a table that is linked to a specific role mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

So I am busy learning MVC and Identity, and I want to know if it is possible to add a table to the database that is linked to a specific role. For example: A role Student and then a table with all the students details etc. 
Is this possible and if it is, how will I go about this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Linked to a specific role"? It can be as simple as naming it properly (probably too weak of a link), all the way to adding SQL security to it (I don't recommend this in this context though.)

In the end, you'll probably settle to "handling the access to this table through application security in your MVC layer", but more information is needed to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to create your student table with all of your students attributes and with a foreign key attribute that links your *AspNetUsers* table to it. Then in your code, when you someone registers with a role of **student** you would take their primary key from the users table and create a new record in the students table with their primary key as the foreign key.

Comment: You (almost) never add a FK to a table you don't own. _AspNetUsers_ is not "his", and it could break upgrades.